# How to hide menu item from fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, menuitem

I want to hide a menuitem from my Menu in my Navigation Drawer.
I tried using setHasOptionsMenu(true) and then adding the method

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    //this is where i tried to hide the item
    menu.findItem(R.id.item).setVisible(false);
}
```

But it says that is null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions, unfortunately it didnt work. Apparently from the fragment the menu is invisible even though i can see it.
What i did was put the menu items static from the activity and in that way i could access to them from the fragment

Answer (score 5):

You should call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your fragment's onCreate() method to allow your fragment to handle menu items. So you could do something like this in your fragment:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
 }
```

And then, you can override onPrepareOptionsMenu method in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
// You can hide the state of the menu item here if you call getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); somewhere in your code
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item); 
    menuItem.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); will call onPrepareOptionsMenu and update your menus.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same problem, if you are using Navigation Drawer and want to play with menu then you have to check the fragment visibility:
Please follow the steps in your Fragment, it worked for me:

1)check for the fragment visibility

```
boolean isMenuVisible  = false;
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    try {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
        if (menuVisible && searchView != null) {
            isMenuVisible  = menuVisible;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CommonUtils.firebaseCrashReport(e);
    }
}
```

2)put this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

2 then just check true value for isMenuVisible and play with menu

```
@Override public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
if(isMenuVisible){
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item);
    menuItem.setVisible(false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with hiding menu item

In activity:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);`
```

In fragment:

```
Menu nav_Menu = context.navigationView.getMenu();<br/>
nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.item_id).setVisible(false);<br>
```

you can pass the activity Context to fragment

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a navigation drawer, you have to get `MenuItem` from it.

Store the `NavigationView` reference in `onCreate` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layoutId);

    ...

    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
}
```

Hide the MenuItem in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean ret = super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem stateBtn = nvDrawer.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item);
    stateBtn.setVisible(true);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate() call

```
setHasOptionMenu(true)
```

and check for the null item in onPrepareOptionsMenu() like so..

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.menu_id);
    if(item!=null)
       item.setVisible(false);
}
```